# Difference between Button and MenuItemImage at Cocos2d-*

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

What is the difference between Button and MenuItemImage?

If I need prepare a menu, does MenuItemImage have something that Button doesn't have?

Using of Button instead of MenuItem is bad practise?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at methods and properties of [ui::Button](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.8/d2/db1/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_button.html) and [MenuItemImage](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.8/d1/d30/classcocos2d_1_1_menu_item_image.html), and see the difference.
For me, if I need menu and management of all the buttons at once, I choose a MenuItem: MenuItemImage, MenuitemSprite or MenuItemLabel.
ui::Button is better if I want to do an object of the buttons, for example, combobox.  Do the ui::Button and more options for the display: you can assign and process separate event handlers for each button’s event;  programmatically  easy to change the color, the size, the label on the button, and font settings during program execution.
Using of ui::Button instead of MenuItem is not a bad practice, it's a matter of choosing the right tool.